# xpath all HTML tags <a> in body except in <footer> limited to x

Tags: xpath

I need to find all HTML tags **a** in the **body** except those from **footer** and limit them to a certain value.

Without any limitation, I have found this :

```
//body | //a[not(ancestor::footer)]
```

Not sure it is correct though.

With the limitation :

```
//body | //a[not(ancestor::footer)]/a[position()<=25]
```

But this not work

Or :

```
//body | //a[not(ancestor::footer)] | /a[position()<=25]
```

But it does not limit anything

What would be the correct syntax to combine conditions ?

Comment: The `|` operator is effectively producing a union of the sequences to the left and right.  So all of your expression attempts are selecting all `body` elements along with everything selected to the right of the `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you should not use `|` there.
Without the amount limitation your XPath could be

```
//body//a[not(ancestor::footer)]
```

While with the limitation of output to 25 results only your XPath will be

```
//body//a[not(ancestor::footer) and position()<=25]
```